# Read from SAS to R for only a subset of rows

Tags: r, sas

I have a very large dataset in SAS (> 6million rows). I'm trying to read that to R. For this purpose, I'm using "read_sas" from the "haven" library in R.

However, due to its extremely large size, I'd like to split the data into subsets (e.g., 12 subsets each having 500000 rows), and then read each subset into R. I was wondering if there is any possible way to address this issue. Any input is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any way you can [split the data with SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438815/whats-the-fastest-way-to-partition-a-sas-dataset-for-batch-processing?rq=1) beforehand ... ?

`read_sas` has `skip` and `n_max` arguments, so if your increment size is `N=5e5` you should be able to set an index `i` to read in the `i`th chunk of data using `read_sas(..., skip=(i-1)*N, n_max=N)`. (There will presumably be *some* performance penalty to skipping rows, but I don't know how bad it will be.)

Comment: Shouldn't be nearly any penalty, if the SAS dataset is uncompressed, as SAS records are fixed length - skip to Nth row is basically just (a) read row length (b) read to N*len.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! I reinstalled the "haven" package, but when I write "skip" and "n_max" inside read_sas, I got an error as such: unused arguments (skip = (2 - 1) * 5e+05, n_max = 5e+05).

Comment: I have `haven` version 2.4.1 (see `packageVersion("haven")`). `library(haven); example("read_sas"); nrow(read_sas(path)); nrow(read_sas(path, skip=100, n_max=25))` works fine/as expected for me.

Comment: My apologies if my comment here may not be directly related to my question above!

My current version of "haven" is 1.1.2. 
So, to upgrade the version I write this:
`require(devtools);`
`install_version("haven", version = "2.4.1")`
But, it gives me the following error: version '2.4.1' is invalid for package 'haven'

Comment: I suspect you have a (very?) old version of R.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/index.html shows version 2.4.1. `install.packages("haven")` *should* install the latest version, which *should* (???) be version 2.4.1 (according to https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/haven/ , version 1.1.2 is from 2018, which is pretty much ancient in R development time ...